# How to display two monitors in full screen at the same time in Virtualbox? Not only one displaying full screen on the VM and the second showing host

Tags: virtualbox, multi-monitor, fullscreen

On *VirtualBox 7*, I've managed to use two monitors.

When in windowed mode, my left and right monitors display each their screen on the Debian VM.
I would like to have them both in Full Screen, to remove the *Windows* *VirtualBox* title bar that uses some place.

When I hit an *Host-F* or *Host-L*, my right monitor stops displaying its *Debian* VM content (it resumes showing host content), and the left one goes full screen.

It's not what I'm willing.
I would like to have both monitors, left and right, to be in Full Screen on the Debian VM.

How may I achieve this?